# Update a Raw Contact

Tags: java, android, contacts

I'm trying to update a contact using the 'new' api. i've got the raw contact ID of the contact and the contact is linked to an account, but i cant find anywhere some sample code or working code that i can study and adapt.

Dunno wherever i have to 'query' the contact first for any info? And is the raw contact ID enough to 'update' a Contact?

At the moment I'm using the `ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)` Is this the best way? and if so what else do i need to add to add details to the contact?

Also i have read somewhere that you have to use something along the lines of `.withSelection(Data.CONTACT_ID = 123... etc` but I'm not too sure..

Any help would be brilliant and Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this SO question. It shows how to update the work number using the new API. Sems to do what you want.

[How to update contact number using Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351545/how-to-update-contact-number-using-android/3351876#3351876)