# Update contact with multiple phone numbers

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I have this code

```
public void updateContact (String contactId, String newNumber) {ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); 

    String selectPhone = Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='"  + 
                     Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'"; 

    String[] phoneArgs = new String[]{contactId};
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
                    .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
                    .build()); 
            try { getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
    }
```

which i took from here [How to update contact number using Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351545/how-to-update-contact-number-using-android) and changed it in order to pass through all my contacts and add to each one of them a prefix of my own.

I run through all contacts and i provide with this
`String id = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));`

the Contact's id to the function above. But some contacts Especially the ones that have multiple numbers and some that have only one number, do not change to get the new prefix even though the given id  is correct?! . 
Do i miss something here i don't know what to change. I think it may be the mime type but i can imagine that someone may not used the Android preinstalled types for phones and used a custom type.
I do not get any errors. Thanks everyone for your time!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally changed my code to work properly, i was passing the contact ID but i needed the phone id ...here is the correct code.

```
public void updateContact (String contactId,  String newNumber) {        


    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(); 
    String selectPhone = Data._ID + "=? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='"  + 
                         Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'"; 

            String[] phoneArgs = new String[]{contactId};
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withSelection(selectPhone, phoneArgs)
                    .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, newNumber)
                    .build()); 
            try {
                getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
    }
```

Do not forget to set the appropriate permissions on android manifest (write contacts)