# How to delete a specific field in a contact?

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I have an issue here, i am able to delete individual contacts fine, My concern is more regarding **deleting specific fields** (Mobile Number, WorkNumner) with in a contact. let me give you a example,

Contact Data:

Name        :  Jhon

email       : abc@gmail.com

**Work Number : 9999999999**

**Work Number : 9999999999**

Now I just want to delete one instance of it, Not both. I have the contact ID and the number to be deleted.

How to proceed from here ? Please help

Comment: is it possible to save same contact number ? i doubt

Comment: yes, you can :(.. Thats where the problem starts

Comment: y dont u put validation itself while adding contatc

Comment: i dont want to interfer with systems save contact feature.. that wont help

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
I suggest you create the contact again without those fields, and delete the previous contact.

Comment: Hi William, Thanks butThat whould be lot of work pulling all  the data and recreating a contacts just to remove a field.. Any other way ?

Comment: In the following link you can see more about updating contacts:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351545/how-to-update-contact-number-using-android

Comment: I suggest you see how both Work Numbers are inserted in the table. Is there something like Work1 Work2 columns? or both numbers are being inserted in the same field separated by a delimiter. After checking, you will have to execute an update to either Work2 (if there are 2 columns) or update the field itself containing both work numbers. You will have to get the correct syntax and query for updating fields ( to Delete, update to null if there are 2 columns for Work ) , otherwise, you'll have if both exist in the same field for example 123456,123456 you'll have to update it to 123456.